# Problema de mutación de tabla con procedimiento y trigger en Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un problema de ingreso de datos con un procedimiento y un trigger. Tengo un procedimiento que copia los datos de TBL_INVERSIONES A TBL_INVERSIONES_PAGOS y en el trigger llamo al procedimiento, el problema está en insertar datos:

*Error starting at line : 1 in command -
INSERT INTO TBL_INVERSIONES (CODIGO_INVERSION, CODIGO_INVERSIONISTA, CODIGO_CUENTA, CODIGO_MONEDA, FECHA_APERTURA, TASA_INTERES, MONTO, FORMA_PAGO_INTERES, FECHA_INICIO, FECHA_FIN, FECHA_ADICION)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 2, TO_DATE('2023-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 5, 40000, 'M', TO_DATE('2023-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2024-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), SYSDATE)
Error report -
ORA-04091: table INVERSIONISTA.TBL_INVERSIONES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "INVERSIONISTA.CALCULAR_PROYECCION_PAGOS", line 4
ORA-06512: at "INVERSIONISTA.TRG_NUEVA_INVERSION_CLIENTE", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'INVERSIONISTA.TRG_NUEVA_INVERSION_CLIENTE'*

Este es mi procedimiento:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALCULAR_PROYECCION_PAGOS AS
BEGIN
  -- Insertar los datos de TBL_INVERSIONES en TBL_INVERSIONES_PAGO
  INSERT INTO TBL_INVERSIONES_PAGO (CODIGO_INVERSION, FECHA_PROYECCION, MONTO_INTERES, MONTO_CAPITAL, PAGADO, FECHA_ADICION)
  SELECT CODIGO_INVERSION, FECHA_FIN, TASA_INTERES, MONTO, 0, SYSDATE
  FROM TBL_INVERSIONES;
END CALCULAR_PROYECCION_PAGOS;
```

Este es mi trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_NUEVA_INVERSION_CLIENTE
AFTER INSERT ON TBL_INVERSIONES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CALCULAR_PROYECCION_PAGOS;
END;
```

Parece estar todo bien pero veo que el error está al momento de hacer el select, probé con está otra solución:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_NUEVA_INVERSION_CLIENTE
AFTER INSERT ON TBL_INVERSIONES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Deshabilitar el trigger temporalmente
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER TRG_NUEVA_INVERSION_CLIENTE DISABLE';

CALCULAR_PROYECCION_PAGOS();

  -- Habilitar el trigger nuevamente
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER TRG_NUEVA_INVERSION_CLIENTE ENABLE';
END;
```

pero está me generaba un error de commit:

*Error starting at line : 1 in command -
INSERT INTO TBL_INVERSIONES (CODIGO_INVERSION, CODIGO_INVERSIONISTA, CODIGO_CUENTA, CODIGO_MONEDA, FECHA_APERTURA, TASA_INTERES, MONTO, FORMA_PAGO_INTERES, FECHA_INICIO, FECHA_FIN, FECHA_ADICION)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 2, TO_DATE('2023-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 5, 40000, 'M', TO_DATE('2023-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2024-11-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), SYSDATE)
Error report -
ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
ORA-06512: at "INVERSIONISTA.TRG_NUEVA_INVERSION_CLIENTE", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'INVERSIONISTA.TRG_NUEVA_INVERSION_CLIENTE'*

**ADJUNTO MIS TABLAS:**

**TBL_INVERSIONES:**

CODIGO_INVERSION    NUMBER,

CODIGO_INVERSIONISTA    NUMBER,

CODIGO_CUENTA   NUMBER,

CODIGO_MONEDA   NUMBER,

FECHA_APERTURA  DATE,

TASA_INTERES    NUMBER(4,2),

MONTO   NUMBER(10,2),

FORMA_PAGO_INTERES  VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),

FECHA_INICIO    DATE,

FECHA_FIN   DATE,

FECHA_ADICION   DATE

---

**TBL_INVERSIONES_PAGO:**

CODIGO_PAGO NUMBER,

CODIGO_INVERSION    NUMBER,

FECHA_PROYECCION    DATE,

MONTO_INTERES   NUMBER(10,2),

MONTO_CAPITAL   NUMBER(10,2),

PAGADO  NUMBER(1,0),

FECHA_ADICION   DATE

Comment: No sé si entiendo mal tu trigger _CALCULAR_PROYECCION_PAGOS_, pero me da la sensación de que cada vez que insertás una fila en _TBL_INVERSIONES_, estás queriendo insertar una y otra vez **todo** el contenido de _TBL_INVERSIONES_ en _TBL_INVERSIONES_PAGO_. ¿Es así? Y, efectivamente, no podés realizar operaciones (incluyendo `SELECT`) sobre una tabla que justamente en ese momento está _mutando_.

Comment: Eeh no solomante insertar una vez, cada nuevo dato que ingreso en tbl_inversiones se debe enviar a tbl_inversiones_pago.

Comment: Entonces, basta simplemente con que pases por parámetros al procedimiento los nuevos valores insertados en _TBL_INVERSIONES_. No es necesario hacer un `SELECT` para obtener esos nuevos valores, siendo que ya los tenés ahí, en el propio trigger.